# Outlook window resize issue

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

**I** am facing a very unique issue. Say, out of 10 times when I start MS Outlook, 8 times it opens in the size as shown below .

[image]

**Things that I have tried**

1. I already tried the method of resizing the window by right clicking the title menu, choosing size, then using the keyboard arrow keys to make the right size. But that did not help.
2. I also used the mouse to resize and then close it but that did not help.
3. I maximized the window and then close the application but that also did not help.

I finally wrote a vb.net application which deletes the registry key named `Frame` in the below location.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Office Explorer
```

The above works but I am now tired of deleting the key everytime. Even after deleting the key, it is recreated in sometime. I recently re-installed Windows and MS Office but the problem did not go away.

Any idea how can I get this sorted permanently?

**Note**: I have researched Google for this and the closest that I have come across is [THIS](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/109072-make-outlook-2016-remember-window-size.html) post. But it did not solve my issue.

Comment: Do you use any cleaning tools, e.g. CCleaner or PrivaZer, that might affect that key?

Comment: I use CCleaner. Does CCleaner creates that key?

Comment: How about testing without CCleaner running?

Comment: Ok let me exit ccleaner and monitor for next 2 days

Comment: CCleaner *deletes* keys, if so desired. It appears you *delete* the key and restart with default dimensions.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: It was too good to be true. I had exited the CCleaner yesterday and the resizing did not happen. But When I started my laptop today, the outlook window resized. I can confirm CCleaner is not running.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Day 2. Still facing the issue. CCleaner os not active